# change the sender number when sending sms

Tags: android

Is it possible to change the sender number when sending an sms from my android program ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is no.

Why??

well thats because the way SMS works. You never send your number, its the service provider which makes sure that senders number is sent.

Comment: Thanks, but what about hiding the number as if the user has turned on "anonymous" setting in his phone ? Is it possible ?

Comment: yet again a no, for the same reason

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to use a third party SMS Gateway. You can reroute the SMS to come from a phone number that you register for your app.

Twilio - http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-i-specify-the-phone-number-a-recipient-sees-when-getting-an-sms-from-my-twilio-app

TextMagic - http://www.textmagic.com/app/pages/en/products/bulk-sms-gateway-api