# Is this possible to hide/Change the sender mobile number while sending sms in android?

Tags: android, sms

How can we hide/change sender's mobile number while sending a SMS to a receiver.

For example if I send a sms to some number 1234567890, the receiver can receive my sms without knowing my number.

I had gone through in couple of Questions in Stack Overflow regarding this and it was mentioned that **it is not possible** to hide / change the sender number.

But I can see some apps in android market which hides the sender SMS number.

Note : In the app, they had clearly mentioned

> Your network-operator must support hiding your caller ID.

I want to know if Network Providers in the US support this option or not. Also how can I find out my Network provider supports this and what API I have to use for hiding the sender's mobile number?

It **would be awesome if I got any clue in this**

Here are the existing questions

- [change the sender number when sending sms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938640/change-the-sender-number-when-sending-sms)
- [How to change sender mobile number in Android SMS service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589306/how-to-change-sender-mobile-number-in-android-sms-service)

Here's the App Link

- [SecretSheep](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sheeptec.SecretSheep.lite)
- [Mr.Hide](https://market.android.com/details?id=europe.mrhide&hl=en)

Comment: look inside these apps: pick app apk, use dex2jar and then jd-gui :)

Comment: As Description in Secret Sheep they clearly written that Indian providers do not support that . (Hide Caller Id)

Answer (score 3):

No.

But what you can do is use an SMS gateway which enables you to hide the callerID or which gives it a specific name. Just an alternative suggestion.

for example take that site, http://api.textmagic.com/ -> http://api.textmagic.com/https-api/textmagic-api-commands#send

Comment: Thanks for your replay, can you give me a hint how you use SMS gateway

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the providers. Mostly they don't support this.

Answer (score 0):

http://learntelecom.com/sms-fraud/

As described in this document SMS faking is impossible without considerable efforts by the technical staff running the SMS-C. In other words, it does not happen either by accident, faulty configuration data or as the result of raw text messages received from the Internet. It happens because in most cases it requires a software patch on the SMS-C. Therefore; any instances of this happening are as the result of direct action by SMS-C staff, and probably in conjunction with assistance from the staff of the Associated PLMN.